# In SQL (PostgreSQL), sum a field based on unique combinations of other fields that are closest to a date value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry couldn't be clearer in the subject line.

Wondering if this is possible (in PostgreSQL).  I have a table like below where I’d like to sum the values of z for specific x and y record combinations that have date values closest to a specific date

```
x    y    z    date
1    1    8    2019-01-01
1    1    14   2019-01-02
1    2    17   2019-01-02
1    2    5    2019-03-03
3    3    41   2019-02-24
1    3    15   2019-06-12
2    1    36   2019-04-18
2    1    71   2019-07-16
2    1    48   2019-06-30
1    1    38   2019-05-23
```

So, as an example, I’d like to sum z for the records with x/y combinations 1/1, 1/2, 2/1 with dates that are closest to, but not after, say 2019-07-01.

The pertinent records of interest in the above scenario are:

```
x    y    z    date
1    1    38   2019-05-23
1    2    5    2019-03-03
2    1    48   2019-06-30
```

where the expected result of the sum of z would be 38+5+48 = 91.

Not sure if there’s a way to do this in a single query (or combinations or subqueries) or if it will take multiple steps.  Something like DISTINCT ON (x,y) … ORDER BY date DESC would have been nice, but it requires the ORDER BY clause to contain the same fields as what’s in the DISTINCT ON clause, which doesn’t work here.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
select sum(z)
from (select distinct on (x, y) t.*
      from t
      where t.date <= '2019-07-01'::date and
            (t.x, t.y) in ( (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1))
      order by x, y, t.date desc
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4d2301a2330c2253c214e893da39d9a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable by combining WHERE clauses with an AND condition.

```
SELECT SUM(z)
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE (( x = 1 AND y = 1) OR ( x = 1 AND y = 2) OR ( x = 2 AND y = 1))
  AND (DATE_PART('day', '2019-07-01' - date) < 7)
```

I chose the value 7 as an interpretation of your 'close to but not after' but you could set it as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In the problem description, it's looking for a record that is closest to or equal to (but not after) the date specified ('2019-07-01' in the example) for each x and y combination.  So in this solution, if there is more than one record with x=1 and y=1 that fall within 7 (or any other arbitrary number) days of the specified date, all of those records would be returned.  The solution from @gordon-linoff addresses this because it only returns one record that is closest to (but not after) for each x and y combination to be summed.